# FileWriter not writing to file with protocol in URL

Tags: java, filewriter

I am using the code below to write to file.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputPath);
writer.append(prettyJson);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

I notice that the content is not written to the file path starts with "file://". Any specific reason for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Java talks about filenames in the form of `String`, the documentation usually says

> The system-dependent filename

and thus it is expecting an "everyday" filename, like `filename.ext`, or something like `c:\some\path\filename.ext` on Windows, or `/some/path/filename.ext` on Unix-likes (this one actually works on both, Java accepts `/` as path separator on Windows too)

For a filename with `file://` protocol, use `URI` and wrap it into a `File`:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(new URI(outputPath)));
```

Comment: Well, given the updates to this answer, I see no further reason to complain about it being the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Simple. You have to stick to the documentation. And the documentation clearly specifies:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File)

```
fileName - String The system-dependent filename.
```

System-dependent means:

- `/path/to/file` on Linux / Mac
- `C:\path\to\file` on Windows

`file://` is not a filename, but a URL, and most commonly used in browsers.

Comment: Not necessarily "for browsers". You can easily have a URL pointing to a local file, and get to the content of that file with Java, see my answer for an example.

Comment: Yah, but that's what it's mainly used for :) To me it sounded like the question was asking for a simplified answer, as OP doesn't seem too experienced.

Comment: Always remember that we strive to create content that is valuable for all future readers. Never restrict yourself to "but the OP has probably limited knowledge" ;-)

Comment: Maybe neither of us got the accept, but at least upvotes can flow freely. And I agree with your comment regarding that accept.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileWriter.html) says:

> public FileWriter(String fileName)
>              throws IOException
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name.

Thus: when using *this* interface, you can not pass an URL, or URI or anything that *legally* could start with `file://`.

In other words: this works as designed. This constructor expects a file name, plain and simple.

If you have a URL-like string, try something like this:

```
URL fileURL = new URL("file://C:/whatever.txt");
InputStream is = fileURL.openStream();
```

Or simply create a File object from that UIR you got. To then pass that file object to a the slightly different constructor of FileWriter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use a relative path go for:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("./" + fileName, true);
```

Comment: No, fileName in itself can be relative, no need for `"./"`. Also, the `true` is wrong.